# Read connectionStrings element of your app.config

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I am trying to read the connection strings from my app.config but it only shows me one connection string and that too isn't in my app.config.

Here's my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

Configuration config = 
ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(
                    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);

foreach (var connectionString in config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print(connectionString.ToString());
```

And it prints out this:

```
data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;
   AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true
```

When I am expecting it to print out a custom connectionString to one of my databases that I have specified in the app.config file.

**Update**

Thank you all for spending time on my problem and trying to help out. Although all of you are right in that I could simply use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings` or access any other subsection this way, I believe when I do that, the configuration is read-only. I cannot make any changes to it, such as add a new connection string or remove an existing one. And I need to do that. Please let me know if there's a way to modify the config file at run-time.

Answer (score 3):

`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionStringName"]` should do it, unless it is stored as an appSetting.

In this case, it would be in `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SettingName"]`

Answer (score 2):

It reads from your machine.config.
After `<connectionStrings>` in app.config insert a `<clear/>.`

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason that you're using `OpenExeConfiguration` to open your configuration file?  If it is an app.config that you created as part of your project, all you have to do is use `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit the ConnectionStrings (or any section in your app.config), you need to use the object returned by GetSection() method of a Configuration object.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConnectionStringsSection csSettings = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") as ConnectionStringsSection;
if(csSettings != null)
{
    // examples of removing all settings, adding a new one and removing it
    csSettings.ConnectionStrings.Clear();
    csSettings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("myCS", "<connectionString>"));
    csSettings.ConnectionStrings.Remove("myCS");
    // save the changes
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

In my experience, there is a bug in the OpenExeConfiguration(string) which means it always opens your app.config. To open a config file from a filename, you need to use OpenMappedExeConfiguration().

Answer (score 0):

Can you read out ANY configuration settings (besides connection string)?

Try:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MyAppVariable");
```

Also, that syntax looks a little complex.  Try this simpler version:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyConnectionString").ConnectionString
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with a small console app I wrote (included in a larger web app solution) - it seemed that my app.config was no longer being picked up at all, and the only connection string I was getting back was LocalSqlServer.

A reboot fixed it.